# Capturing a session with an application for debugging purposes (linux)

Tags: linux, debugging, x11, capture, vnc

I would like to record all interaction with a (linux) application to disk, capturing the UI and events like keystrokes and mouse clicks. Ideally this could weightless, always-on, scoped to a specific process, and writing cyclically to temp disk until an issue occurs. At which time we can notify developers and replay the bug.

I'm wondering if there is some thing like `x11vnc` or the like that can be pointed at an application window/parent process and spool the results to disk. For privacy's sake, it would be best to limit recording to output from a specific process, and not a general screen capture.

Does anyone know of such a solution, preferably using fundamental linux tooling rather than high-level tools like `OBS Studio`?

Regards,
Jason